# display elements of matrix by disp() is showing error that there are too many output arguments

Tags: matlab, matrix, disp

i have a 512x512 uint8 image , i want to display the matrix elements of the image , i have used disp() , but an error occured saying( Error using disp .Too many output arguments.) How should I display the elements of matrix of the image.

program is

```
Z=imread('C:\Documents and Settings\ms polichand\My Documents\Downloads\brodatz.tiff');
figure();
imshow(Z);
A=disp(Z);
```

error is

Error using disp
Too many output arguments.

Error in imagematrix (line 6)
A=disp(Z);

what should I do?

Comment: if you want to see the actual pixel values get rid of the semi-colon (;) after calling imread, or simply write 'Z' in the command window

Comment: disp() shows something in the command line, its not for "saving" the variables in A. Z already has the numbers you want.

Comment: Actually i need the pixel values in the code ,i have to use the matrix to reshape it to row vector.

Comment: @CicilaMadassery those are already in `Z` are they not?

Comment: yes, but how can i use that matrix in order to reshape it to a row vector in my code

Comment: could you please tell me how can i take that matrix and perform reshape operation on it to convert that matrix into a row vector

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you have too many **output** arguments. Your code was

```
A=disp(Z);
```

The output arguments are anything to the left of the `=` so in this case `A`. Since you only have one single output argument* and the error says that that is too many then logically it means that the `disp` function accepts only *zero* output arguments. In other words you can only call it like this:

```
disp(Z)
```

*Note: a common example of having more than one output argument is `[m,n]=size(Z)`

Comment: thank you,  could you please tell me how can i take that matrix and perform reshape operation on it to convert that matrix into a row vector.

Comment: @CicilaMadassery try the very cryptically named [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function. That really couldn't have been hard to google yourself...

Comment: @CicilaMadassery but a shortcut is `Z(:).'`

Comment: @Dan The transpose does not reshape a matrix into a row vector

Comment: @excaza the `(:)` reshapes to a column vector, transposing a column vector gives you a row vector

Comment: @Dan oops, duh. I shouldn't SO before coffee!